# Iterating an ArrayList to return a value

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

I am having trouble seeing the error of my work: I am creating an iterator (in my class LamborghiniCarLot) which will give the number of vehicles in my (ArrayList inventory;) which are rear-wheel-drive. the Lamborghini class has a method called getIsRearWheelDrive(). But attempting to call it, I get the method not found. "inventory" is the field variable holding the arraylist. Here is my code as it stands:

```
public int howManyAreRearWheelDrive()
{
    int numberRearWheel = 0;
    Iterator<Lamborghini> it = inventory.iterator();
    Lamborghini inv = null;

    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        inv = it.next();
        if(inv != null)
        {
            if(it.getIsRearWheelDrive() == true)
            {
                numberRearWheel ++;
            }
        }
    }
    return numberRearWheel;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(it.getIsRearWheelDrive() == true)
```

should be

```
if(inv.getIsRearWheelDrive() == true)
```

Comment: or just `if(inv.getIsRearWheelDrive())`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `it.getIsRearWheelDrive()` you need to use `inv.getIsRearWheelDrive()` since your Lamborghini class has the method. `it` is your iterator and an iterator does not have a `getIsRearWhileDrive()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a for loop

```
for(Lamborghini inv: inventory) {
  if(inv.getIsRearWheelDrive()) numberRearWheel++;
}
```

or a Stream

```
public int howManyAreRearWheelDrive() {
  return (int)inventory.stream().filter(inv -> inv.getIsRearWheelDrive()).count();
}
```